# Python for loop increment

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, increment

How is this working and for loop increment doesn’t work?

```
for i in range(0,10):
   if i == 3:
       i = i + 1
       continue
   print(i)
```

Comment: this works just like it should be, please give the code which does not work

Comment: On every iteration `i` is replaced with the next value from the `range` independent of any earlier change to it's value.

Comment: You can try debugging to understand the flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the code,

```py
for i in range(0,10):
   if i == 3:
       i = i + 1
       continue
   print(i)
```

the output is going to be,

```
0
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**Breaking down the code,**

`for i in range(0, 10)`

for loop runs for i=0 to i=9, each time initializing i with the value 0 to 9.

```
if i == 3:
 i = i + 1
 continue
print(i)
```

when i = 3, above condition executes, does the operation `i=i+1` and then `continue`, **which looks to be confusing you**, so what `continue` does is it will jump the execution to start the next iteration without executing the code after it in the loop, i.e. `print(i)` would not be executed.

This means that for every iteration of `i` the loop will print `i`, but when i = 3 the `if` condition executes and `continue` is executed, leading to start the loop for next iteration i.e. i=4, hence the 3 is not printed.

Answer (score 2):

In the provided code when you try to use `i` in a for loop with range, it always changes to the number provided by range in the function without bothering to look at the increment made to `i`. so basically if you try `list(range(0, 10))` this will give you `[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. so for goes through that list one by one without thinking if any changes were made to `i` or not.

which if seen

```
loop_1: i=0
loop_2: i=1
loop_3: i=2
loop_4: i=3 (here now you increment value by 1), i=4
loop_5: i=4 (but the for loop was going though the list from range function so the change didn't do anything)
loop_6: i=5 (and so on until 9)
```

Comment: That really makes sense @xcodz-dot. we can use a while loop in this case.